# Prevent PHP public function from reference outside namespace?

Tags: php

Is there a way to construct a PHP application class such that the public functions are accessible ONLY to other classes in the same namespace?

Comment: No, there isn't unfortunately. There may be work-arounds available, but not inherently, no, there isn't

Comment: The only way this would be possible is by examining the [backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but that is really horrible.

Comment: Why not use `protected` functions and extend the classes in your namespace from one another?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may do so with reflection, assuming all of these classes in a namespace extend the base abstraction class that defines this principle.

http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getnamespacename.php

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/GcGscR

Comment: How does that prevent other code (from outside the namespace) to access the public methods?

Comment: See this example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/GcGscR - Note that i'm using function array dereferencing which is only available in PHP 5.4 or greater.

Comment: You don't really need to use the reflection for that. The actual magic is in the examination of the debug trace.

Comment: I tend to disagree but I do believe this answers your question, not the answer specifically but the comment with provided example.

Comment: While I understand this "workaround", I was actually looking for something that did not require me changing 100's of classes in my existing application. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: This is not a 'workaround', it's how to accomplish what you asked about. You have two viable options to incorporate this from the top of my head. You can put that code in a base, abstract class, and have classes that you want in your 'single namespace principle' extend said class. Another option, is to modify the code to fit within your autoloader than will perform the checks from there, that will require no modification of your other files and rather just one.

Comment: Sorry but the codepad link above seems to show nothing of substance.

Comment: @TJChambers - You've seen it months ago in July when you asked the question, telling me it was a 'workaround'. Why you are coming back 3 months later to tell me my paste no longer works when I know you saw it before is beyond me or my ability to assist you. Good luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: Appreciate your good wishes. Being able to reconsider it now as a suitable "workaround" for me is out of the question if I can't use the link you provided.